# android-What does Build.MANUFACTURER return on htc devices

Tags: android, build

Obviously I know it will return htc but is it caps or lower case? I recently had a user of one of my apps tell me one of the functions crashed his phone so I want to exclude that function from htc devices for the time being based on what I get from Build.MANUFACTURER and also Build.VERSION.SDK_INT. I just have no idea what will return from Build.MANUFACTURER on an htc device or other devices for that matter. Does anyone know of a list somewhere that would have all that type of info?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices) link for a list of manufacturers.

Here is how I detect whether or not a device is manufactured by HTC. Note that I don't care whether or not it matches HTC or htc exactly, I toLower() it and check to see if Build.MANUFACTURER CONTAINS htc at all.

```
public boolean isAnHTCDevice() {
    String manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
    if (manufacturer.toLowerCase().contains("htc"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

EDIT (almost two years later) - modified code and added TVK's recommendation:

```
public boolean isAnHTCDevice() {
    String manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
    return manufacturer.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).contains("htc");
}
```

Shortened return statement, added Local.ENGLISH to .toLowerCase as recommended by Lint.

Comment: lol right on man thanks I know that'll work. Sometimes after working on the more complicated pieces of an application the simpler parts tend to escape my grasp :p

Comment: Note that toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH) will be the preferred version of this, as recommended by Lint warnings.